# choosing points in grid such that every small rectangle contains a point

Tags: combinatorics, probabilistic-method

I've started reading the article ["ɛ-nets and simplex range queries"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf02187876) and I found a weaker claim that i've been told can be proved more easily:

**Prove** that there is a constant $C > 0$ so that for every sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, one can choose exactly one point inside each grid square $[n, n + 1) × [m, m + 1) ⊂ \mathbb{R}^2
, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so that every rectangle of dimensions $\epsilon \times (\frac{C}{\epsilon}) log(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ in the plane (not necessarily axis-aligned)
contains at least one chosen point.

It was hinted that the problem can be solved using the [Local Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma) however I can't see how. Using compactness arguments I understand that it suffice to prove this for a bounded grid, but I don't understand how can the events could be defined.

ANY help would be appreciated